# What does "some type of sheep meat" mean

Tags: idioms

I read a comment on StackOverflow about "What is depending typing?". And the poster complained about Wikipedia's hard-to-read article about dependent typing. The exact comment is:

> Well, the article opens with lambda cubes, which sound like some type of sheep meat to me. Then it goes on to discuss λΠ2 systems, and as I don't speak alien I skipped that section. Then I read about the calculus of inductive constructions, which incidentally seems to have little to do with calculus, heat transfer, or construction. After giving a language comparison table, the article ends, and I am left more confused than when I got to the page

What does "some type of sheep meat" mean? It seems to be "familiar stuff" since the sentence is supposed to introduce what OP can understand and then give the contrasting obtuse stuff next to it.

Comment: Obviously λΠ2 was all Greek to him.

Comment: Could you link to the question, please?  You've made me curious...

Comment: @jamesqf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338709/what-is-dependent-typing

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It is a joke

"Lambda cubes" sounds like "lamb cubes" and lamb is the meat of a young sheep. So "Lamb cubes" would be sheep meat cut into blocks.

Comment: I think it would be considered a pun, rather than a joke.

Comment: @jamesqf puns are a type of joke

Comment: @user253751 According to [Oscar Levant](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/78070-a-pun-is-the-lowest-form-of-humor-when-you-don-t), the lowest type.

Comment: Just want to add a little more detail and point out that nothing about the phrase "some type of sheep meat" is idiomatic. It's a phrase unique to this very specific situation.

Comment: @Barmar Aye, one should definitely feel sheepish for stooping so low...

Comment: This was a baaaaaaaad pun

Comment: @user253751: Many people would disagree :-)

Comment: @Ernest Friedman-Hill - Wool you please stop this silliness.

Answer (score 4):

"Lambda Cubes" sounds like "Lamb Cubes", a culinary ingredient.

Additionally, "Some type of sheep meat" refers to inexpensive replacement with meat from an old lamb. Thus, a trick.

Lambs grow up to be sheep.

Comment: "_Lambs grow up to be sheep._" Unless they get turned into lamb cubes...

Comment: @TripeHound: What a great username for that comment

Comment: @TripeHound. Lambs grow up to be sheep, unless you're [Tomasz Schafernaker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fODSl7NEsSk).

Comment: Lambs ARE sheep.  Just as children ARE people.